# How to handle username in Cocoa Touch?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a login view controller that uses the php/mysql/POST function to verify if a user is authorized.  Once authorized, they enter the application.

My question is, once they are in the application, how do I "grab" their username and use it to append to any data that they upload to my database while they are in my app?

I am assuming I append it to my current NSMutableData string that carries the text blocks that they upload, but how would I "grab" this username to append it?

Assuming I have two view controllers, "login" and "main", and the content is being uploaded on "main", how do I pass the username from the "login" view to the "main" view so that I can append it when the user hits the upload button (which resides on the main view)?

EDIT: Where I want this username retrieved is in the following:

```
-(IBAction)uploadImage:(id)sender  {
NSLog(@"uploadImage");



//and for retrieval





NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *authenticatedUsersName = [defaults objectForKey:@"username"];


NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:kPostURL]; 



[postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", kText, textField.text]];



[postString setString:[postString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not concerned with security of a username, why don't you store the username in `NSUserDefaults` upon successful authentication?  You can do something like this....

```
//upon authentication...

NSUserDefault *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"username"] == nil) //we haven't saved anything yet
     [defaults setObject:authenticatedUsersName forKey:@"username"];

[defaults synchronize];  //saves the new defaults

//and for retrieval

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *authenticatedUsersName = [defaults objectForKey:@"username"];
```

I think this design gives you more flexibility so you can use the username across all view controllers in your app.

*post re-edit*

Why can't you just format the string somewhere in this function?  Whats the exact post url format?

```
    -(IBAction)uploadImage:(id)sender  {
    NSLog(@"uploadImage");

    //and for retrieval     

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *authenticatedUsersName = [defaults objectForKey:@"username"];

    //MY CHANGES, CAN YOU DO EITHER OF THESE?

    NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@", kPostURL, authenticatedUsersName]; 

    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@&%@", kText, textField.text, authenticatedUsersName]];

    [postString setString:[postString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

}
```

Comment: I will try this tonight and will let you know if I am able to insert/adapt this successfully into my current code.  Seems straightforward, and thanks for the quick response!  If it works, I will be sure to let you know how thankful I am by commenting here and clicking the checkmark.  Otherwise, I may have some brief follow up items to sew it all together successfully.... : )

Comment: Ha, that was by far the most polite comment I've ever gotten here.  Happy to help, welcome to iOS development, hope you love it :-D.

Comment: Hi Convolution.  So, I think I almost got it, but I am running into a bit of a snag.  The place where I need to "retrieve" the username is within an IBAction called "uploadImage".  This encompasses an NSMutableString, which I use to pass some other variables thru to a .php file for sql storage purposes.  I need to pass authenticatedUsersName as well, but I am not able to append an NSString inside of an NSMutableString.  I have updated my question above to reflect where I want to append the "username".  Can you help out?

Comment: The post url format is "http://www.example.com/upload.php"....
Do I need the question mark on the end?  Or does your format need the question mark?

Comment: Convolution:  You have no idea how helpful you have been.  I cannot put into words how much I have learned in such a short amount of time thru your post.  This has been one of the most incredible experiences I have had on StackOverflow.  If there is any way I can compensate you in any way, you got it my friend.  Simply incredible.  You nailed it.  It was the second method in your response that did it.  I reverted the first line back to my original code, and used your second line.  THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Happy to help Mike, I hope all future inquiries you may have are as helpful as this one and you're enjoying iOS development as much as I do :-D.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method of having globally available variables is to use a singleton class.

This is slightly more difficult than Convolution's solution using NSUserDefaults, but it suits some use cases better.

There is a good tutorial at the following location:
http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/